# WDS Bridging on TP-LINK doesn't work

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, wds

I have two routers: one is set up as DHCP, and the other TP-Link I want to configure as a wireless range extender.

I followed the TP-Link FAQs [here](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-440.html) and [here](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-227.html). I have completed these exact steps. My phone still cannot connect connect to the extended SSID, as it's stuck at obtaining an IP address (DHCP is disabled in one of the steps).

Should I be connecting to the original SSID?

Answer (score 3):

Flagging the "DHCP Relay" checkbox worked for me. WDS bridging between portable 4G modem/router and an Archer D7 used as Wi-Fi range extender. Here details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301890/wds-router-doesnt-forward-dhcp-packets/65657032#65657032

Answer (score 1):

Since you've disabled the DHCP server, your phone can't get IP settings automatically, so you should enter them manually.